# WCF service And Linq

Tags: linq, wcf

I am using LINQ in a WCF service. I am trying to list all my movies in a grid but my query wont work.
any of you know why?

this is the query:

```
public List<MovieInfo> GetAllMovies()
    {          
            var queryResult = (from x in db.MovieInfos
                               select x);
            return queryResult.ToList();                   
    }
```

This is the webconfig:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add 
      name="dmaa0913Sem3_1ConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Data Source=dbname;Initial Catalog=dataname;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

here is the error i get:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

The service is online, because i use WCF test client.

Comment: take a look at the config generated in wcf test client, and compare it to the config in the client application.

Comment: If you can't get as far as successfully calling the WCF service I fail to see how this is a LINQ question or how the LINQ code snippet helps. What am I missing? Have you gone through the possible problems and solutions suggested by the error message?

Comment: I can successfully, insert, update and delete. I just cant "extract" objects from the database, sorry if not the correct word for it. I also have another service called Users, where i have the exact same query. But where i select from db.Users insteadt of db.movieinfos and that works. Yes i have tried going trough the error message and can't understand why it makes the error.

Comment: How are you hosting the service?  IIS, Windows Service, console app, etc?  How are you calling the service?  The most likely culprits are a) the client config is wrong, b) the service isn't running or c) there's an issue with the service config.  Posting your service and client configs and an example of how you are calling the service from your client will help us help you.  As it stands now, there's not enough information in your post to give you anything more than "try this, that and this".

Comment: I am using the WCF test client to call the query. I just use the invoke button in there to test it. I am hosting it with IIS

Comment: @KevinJensen - What is the service address you are using?  Can you go the service address in a browser and get the "You have created a service" page?  Can you add the code where you call the service in your client?  Or are you getting this error in the WCFTestClient?

Comment: @Tim - Yes i can go to the site in a browser. Yes i am getting the error in the WCFTestClient. And i only get the error when i call the GetAllMovies() and when i call another function that i called GetMovieById(). I have three additional functions where i can SaveMovie(), DeleteMovie() and UpdateMovie all those three works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The query that i use for extracting data from the database i somthing called lazyloading. And WCF have trouble working with this kind of query if the data that need's to be extracted is to complex. It is somthing about how WCF service serialize the service. So what i did to make it work was to go in the Linq datacontex and set the. Serialization Mode to Unidirectional. This worked for me.